# Using a local HTML file in jsoup

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I've been trying to parse a html file that is stored locally on  my C: drive but I keep getting the same error

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\MyStuff\MyHTMLFile.html (The system cannot find the file specified)`

This is my code.

`Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new File("C:\\MyStuff\\MyHTMLFile.html"), "UTF-8");`

I've tried different variations of back and forward slashes but nothing seems to work?

Comment: So are you sure that the file's there and that the user has read permissions?

Comment: does the MyStuff Directory exist?

Comment: Yes the directory and file definitely exist. I tried putting it in my workspace as well in case it was a permission issue but still same error?

Comment: Could you post the entire stacktrace?

Comment: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\MyStuff\MyHTMLFile.html (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
 at org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil.load(DataUtil.java:36)
 at org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(Jsoup.java:103)
 at HTMLParserExample1.main(HTMLParserExample1.java:30)
`

Comment: I followed the instructions here if this makes any difference? http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-file 
Also I can successfully parse HTML using jsoup directly from a webpage no problem

Comment: You are trying to load a file from your PC HD to an app running in the emulator? You need to have the file stored on the emulator

Comment: Sorry I shouldn't have used the tag 'Android'. This piece of code is ultimately destined for use in an Android app but right now I'm just testing it in a simple java application, it's easier to debug instead of having to run the emulator every time I make a change

Comment: I've made some progress. I created a new file called test.html and it has one line of text. It was parsed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Seems as though the file was corrupt or something? I copied the contents into a new file and its working okay now.